# How to use "user_id" in Sqlalchemy models if "user" is in another service?

Tags: sqlalchemy, rabbitmq, microservices, fastapi, alembic

I am writing my first project on microservices.

1. Authorization service. He has his own database in which the "user" is stored. Registration and authorization in this service.
2. Meeting planning service. I want this service to communicate with the first one using RabbitMQ. But I haven't gotten to that yet. I stopped at creating models and migrations.
   I can't apply migrations because my service has no connection with the first one, that is, I don't have a user. What should I do? Tell me please

I couldn't really Google anything

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4ukV.png)

Comment: The `relationship` in your model can't reference an external service - it's a reference to a different table/orm-object in the same instance as where that application lives. You'll generally just store a user id (which is returned from your authorization service) and/or user name - you can keep a locally cached copy of this, but you'll have to create a User table in that case, which is a locally cached version of what your authorization service provides (updated each time the user logs in or if you haven't re-fetched the data in x minutes/hours/days/etc.).